# session is null in wcf service after several calls

Tags: wcf, session

I have a website that's totally built on wcf services , all my html is generated by wcf services and also all events are in wcf services . the website is working fine but after four or five wcf services calls , the session gets lost , if I refresh the page then everything goes back but also after 4 or 5 calls the same thing happens . and the biggest problem is that on localhost this doenst appear only on live environment , any idea where to start with this problem ?

here is sample code :

```
 [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetMemberRank")]
    public string GetMemberRank()
    {
        StringBuilder returnResult = new StringBuilder();
        //a call to fix current culture of this current thread.
        Helper.InitializeServiceCall(null);
```

and this is the end of the call

```
     //Set the http status code
            currentContext.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            //set the msg
            currentContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Action", messageTypeText);
```

and this is some javascript

```
  $.ajax({
        url: this.URL,
        dataType: this.DataType,
        type: this.Type,
        processData: false,
        contentType: ContentType,
        data: ContentType == 'application/json' ? JSON.stringify(this.Data) : this.Data,
        success: function (returnedResult, statusText, jqXHR) {
```

Comment: Any code? What is the session time out set to?

Comment: It's set to the max darren , 1440 minutes . i'll add little code to the question